# Assign n individuals to 4 out of 6 available workshops at conference.

Tags: combinatorics

we're currently planning a conference which will offer guests 6 workshops, 4 of which are mandatory for the participants. The six workshops occur in parralel in four individual timeslots. The 90 participants already gave us their workshop preference. The workshop rooms are of different sizes and can therefore only host limited amount of people.

How can I assign the participants (most evenly) according to their preferences under the workshop room constraint?

Please find the anonymized data [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwt5g0s0E6k5OHh6VjNTTU1MTms/view?usp=sharing)

Help, this is giving me a headache.
Thanks!

Regards
Fill

Comment: Given the current set-up, it's not possible to fulfill everyone's preferences. In particular, not everyone who wanted to attend Workshop 6 will be able to; given that there are 70 preference entries for WS6, but only 4 sessions with capacity 15, some people are going to be unhappy.

Your question is about how to make it so the assignment is made according to their preferences "most evenly." There are many interpretations of that, what does this mean exactly? What matters the most to you?

Comment: Also, can you switch rooms? The above constraint may not apply if you switch the rooms of the popular WS6 (70 prefer) with the less-popular WS2 (42 prefer).